# How to change the value of a variable depending on a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a small program that shows how long it takes a certain vehicle to orbit a planet. Eg a car at 100mph orbits earth (7917 miles) in 79.17 hours and etc.

To display vehicles I've used icons and to display planets I've used img. I can give values to icons (in this case I've given them their speed values as in mph) But for images I can't give values for some reason which I wanted to use as the radius of the planets.

Currently I have

```
 let icons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.icon-container .fa')];
 let answerContainer = document.getElementById("answer-container");
 let answerDiv = document.getElementById("answer-div");
 let planetImgs = [...document.querySelectorAll(".planet-container img")];


//Function to slide icons User clicks right/left to show next/previous vehicle icon

 function adjustActive (adjustment) { 
 var current = icons.find(it => it.id === 'active'); 
 var currentIndex = icons.indexOf(current);
 var nextIndex = (currentIndex + adjustment) % icons.length;

 if (nextIndex < 0) nextIndex = icons.length - 1;
current.removeAttribute('id');
icons[nextIndex].id = 'active'; 

// Action to find Orbital Period
let planet = 7917.5;  **(I WANT THIS TO CHANGE DEPENDING ON THE FUNCTION BELOW)**
let nextElement = document.getElementById("active");
let nextElements = nextElement.getAttribute("value")
let orbitalPeriod = planet / nextElements;

answerDiv.innerHTML = orbitalPeriod.toFixed(2);

}

// Function to slide planets - User clicks right/left to show next/previous planet

function adjustActivePlanet (adjustment) { 
var current = planetImgs.find(it => it.id === 'active-planet'); 
var currentIndex = planetImgs.indexOf(current);
var nextIndex = (currentIndex + adjustment) % icons.length;

if (nextIndex < 0) nextIndex = planetImgs.length - 1;
current.removeAttribute('id');
planetImgs[nextIndex].id = 'active-planet'; 

} // The value of this function needs to be used in the function above for let "planets"

//Arrow Buttons

document.querySelector('#left-arrow').addEventListener('click', e => adjustActive(-1));
document.querySelector('#right-arrow').addEventListener('click', e => adjustActive(1));
document.querySelector('#left-arrow-planet').addEventListener('click', e => adjustActivePlanet(-1));
document.querySelector('#right-arrow-planet').addEventListener('click', e => adjustActivePlanet(1));



    <div class="main-container">
    <div class="object-container">
        <div class="icon-container">
            <i class="fa fa-car" id="active" value="100"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bicycle" value="25"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-plane" value="500"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-ship" value="10"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" value="1000"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle" value="3000"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow-buttons">
            <a href="#" class="right-arrow" id="right-arrow"></a>
            <a href="#" class="left-arrow" id="left-arrow"></a>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="answer-container" id="answer-container">
            <div id="answer-div"></div>
            <h3>Hours to orbit</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="planet-container">
            <img src="images/earth planet.png" alt="" id="active-planet">
            <img src="images/saturn planet.png" alt="" class="planet">
            <img src="images/neptune planet.png" alt="" class="planet">
            <img src="images/mercury planet.png" alt="" class="planet">
            <img src="images/sun.png" alt="" class="planet">
            <img src="images/mars planet.png" alt="" class="planet">
            <div class="arrow-buttons">
                <a href="#" class="right-arrow" id="right-arrow-planet"></a>
                <a href="#" class="left-arrow" id="left-arrow-planet"></a>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see above, the let planet = 7917.5 is earths radius, so the answer container will output the value of "planet" / the value of the active icons "active". How can I make the value of "planet" change depending on which planet is currently active ("active-planet"). For example neptune is 30,000 so I want the "planet" value to be 30,000 / the value of the icon (car 100mph).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `value` attribute you can use a `data-<name>` attribute.

ie.

```
<img src="images/neptune planet.png" alt="" class="planet" data-radius="30000">
```

Then you can access this value with:

```
document.querySelector('#active-planet').dataset.radius
```

EDIT: I've added a runnable snippet example to show how I would approach your program.

I find it helps to break down the related logic into individual functions, particularly when I want to use the same logic in multiple places (in each button listener).

In this case ive created a `setActiveClasses()` function and `renderOrbitDuration()` function.

We keep track of the active vehicle and planet using an index (0, 1, 2, etc...) for each (`activeVehicleIndex` and `activePlanetIndex`).

The buttons simply increment and decrement the relevant index and then the `setActiveClasses()` function and `renderOrbitDuration()` function use this index to set the right active classes and render the orbital duration.

Read through and run the snippet below.

```js
let activeVehicleIndex = 0
let activePlanetIndex = 0

const vehicleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.vehicles i')
const planetElements = document.querySelectorAll('.planets img')

function setActiveClasses () {
  // Clear old active classes
   [...vehicleElements, ...planetElements].forEach(el => {
    el.classList.remove('active')
  })
  
  // Add new active classes
  vehicleElements[activeVehicleIndex].classList.add('active')
  planetElements[activePlanetIndex].classList.add('active')
}

function renderOrbitDuration () {
  activeVehicleEl = vehicleElements[activeVehicleIndex]
  activePlanetEl = planetElements[activePlanetIndex]
  
  const html = `
    Vehicle Name: ${activeVehicleEl.dataset.name}<br>
    Vehicle Speed: ${activeVehicleEl.dataset.speed}<br>
    Planet Name: ${activePlanetEl.dataset.name}<br>
    Planet Radius: ${activePlanetEl.dataset.radius}<br>
    Orbital Period: ${activePlanetEl.dataset.radius / activeVehicleEl.dataset.speed}
  `
  
  document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = html
}

// Previous/Next Button Listeners
document.querySelector('.vehicles .prev').addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeVehicleIndex-- // Decrement activeVehicleIndex
  if (activeVehicleIndex < 0) { activeVehicleIndex = 0 } // Dont allow negative values
  setActiveClasses()
  renderOrbitDuration()
})

document.querySelector('.vehicles .next').addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeVehicleIndex++ // Increment activeVehicleIndex
  if (activeVehicleIndex > vehicleElements.length - 1) { activeVehicleIndex = vehicleElements.length - 1 } // Dont allow values greater than number of vehicles
  setActiveClasses()
  renderOrbitDuration()
})

document.querySelector('.planets .prev').addEventListener('click', () => {
  activePlanetIndex-- // Decrement activePlanetIndex
  if (activePlanetIndex < 0) { activePlanetIndex = 0 } // Dont allow negative values
  setActiveClasses()
  renderOrbitDuration()
})

document.querySelector('.planets .next').addEventListener('click', () => {
  activePlanetIndex++ // Increment activePlanetIndex
  if (activePlanetIndex > planetElements.length - 1) { activePlanetIndex = planetElements.length - 1 } // Dont allow values greater than number of planets
  setActiveClasses()
  renderOrbitDuration()
})

// Run both of these once on page load to set initial classes and render values
setActiveClasses()
renderOrbitDuration()
```

```css
.vehicles, .planets {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.vehicles .active {
  color: red;
}

.planets .active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Vehicles -->
<div class="vehicles">
  <i class="fa fa-car" data-name="car" data-speed="100"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-bicycle" data-name="bike" data-speed="25"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plane" data-name="plane" data-speed="500"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-ship" data-name="ship" data-speed="10"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" data-name="fighter jet" data-speed="1000"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle" data-name="space shuttle" data-speed="3000"></i>
  <div>
    <button class="prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Planets -->
<div class="planets">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" data-name="earth" data-radius="6000"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" data-name="saturn" data-radius="60000"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" data-name="neptune" data-radius="25000"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" data-name="mercury" data-radius="2500"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" data-name="sun" data-radius="700000"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" data-name="mars" data-radius="3500"/>
  <div>
    <button class="prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Output -->
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: How can I access the data radius? Would it be let planet = active-planet.dataset.radius? That would be ideal!

Comment: Its not working, I cant seem to access the data-radius and apply it to my "planets" variable/

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('#active-planet').dataset.radius`

Comment: I've done let currentPlanet = document.getElementById("active-planet"); and let planet = currentPlanet.dataset.radius; It does seem to be receiving the data for earth but not for the other "active" planets when they are active

Comment: I've added a runnable example that should help

Comment: Ah fair enough, ive noticed quite a few things changed around? Is it worth me keeping my code or any way i could implement this in my current code? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the runnable example is a re-write from scratch based on your desired outcome rather than the code you supplied. I recommend reading through and understanding how the example works. I think, at least, its worth using the `activeIndex` method of keeping track of the active vehicle/planet to determine which speed/radius to use.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, the finished app is on my website momiah.co (5th project). That's how I want it to look and feel, any chance you could take a look and tell me what you think? If you notice, the calculation does work (took part of your code) but the problem is that it only calculates when you click the arrows on the vehicle container but doesnt change when you click the arrows on the planet container